# expected expression else if error

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement

This bit is being troublesome....

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
//1
NSString *urlString = @"http://zaphod_beeblebrox.pythonanywhere.com/";
//2
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
//3
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//4
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
//5
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError         *error) {
                           if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) (UIWebView)
                        else if ((error != nil) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error))}];

}@end
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing else if to have problems. I have googled the crap out of this and have checked my code over and over, but I cant seem to figure this out!

please help.

Comment: What is the problem you are observing? It seems that your code is incomplete as posted. Are you getting a compiler error?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out what you are doing. At all.

Comment: This code makes no sense: `if (…) (UIWebView) else if …`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: else if keeps getting an expected expression error, I have no extra semi colons or anything else that most people have when this error comes up. I haven't had any compiler errors yet. I am trying to use a uiwebview to bring up a web app. If you know of any better way, please let me know! Here is the sight where I got most of the code: [link] (http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/nslog/nslognsstringexample.html)

Comment: Why are you using `NSURLConnection`? In my answer below, I show you a much simpler way of doing it, using `loadRequest`. But I also show you how to fix this code if you really want to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

You asked this same question before, which [I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12720171/1271826). I repeat the relevant portions of that answer below. If there's something that didn't make sense, just leave a comment below.

---

I'm guessing you're trying to load a html page in a `UIWebView`? You obviously need an `IBOutlet` for your `UIWebView`. (If you're not familiar with `IBOutlet`, check out the Apple tutorial [Your First iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/RM_YourFirstApp_iOS/Articles/00_Introduction.html).)

Anyway, in my examples below, I'm going to assume your `IBOutlet` is called `webview`, and thus I might advise getting rid of the `NSOperationQueue` and `NSUrlConnection` and just have the `UIWebView` load the html for you:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString     *urlString = @"http://zaphod_beeblebrox.pythonanywhere.com/";
    NSURL        *url       = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request   = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [self.webview loadRequest:request];
}
```

It might be worth going through a few iPhone programming tutorials (just google it and you'll get tons of hits), too or look at the Apple [App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/Introduction.html) or check out the wonderful resources at http://developer.apple.com.

---

**Update:**

By the way, if you insist on using `NSOperationQueue` and `NSUrlConnection`, you still need an `IBOutlet` for your webview. But the revised code would look like:

```
NSString         *urlString = @"http://zaphod_beeblebrox.pythonanywhere.com/";
NSURL            *url       = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest     *request   = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue     = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:queue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
                           {
                               NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:data.bytes];
                               [self.webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:url];
                           }
                           else if (error != nil)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               NSLog(@"No data returned");
                           }
                       }];
```

I think `loadRequest` is much simpler, but if you really want to do it this way, here you go.

Comment: +1 for your patience with this poster.

Answer (score 1):

' I am trying to use a uiwebview to bring up a web app. If you know of any better way, please let me know!'

```
[theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 different errors. First "(UIWebView)" doesn't mean anything, and secondly, if you had a statement there that did mean something it would need a semicolon after it. Thirdly, there should be a semicolon after NSLog(@"Error: %@", error).  It would be better to put some of the code on separate lines for readability -- it should look like this:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
        ;//a valid expression here with a semicolon at the end
    else if (error != nil)
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
```

That being said, you should use the method that @Rob posted to make your code work.